# Limsup and inf swap

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

I'm reading a paper where $\limsup$ and $\inf$ are interchanged:

$$\limsup_{D \backepsilon \text{ }x \rightarrow x_0} \bigg( \inf_n \textbf{E}^x \big[ \textbf{1}_{\{\forall t \in (0,h-1/n]: B(t) \in D)\}} \big] \bigg) \leq \inf_k \bigg(\limsup_{D \backepsilon \text{ }x \rightarrow x_0} \textbf{E}^x \big[ \textbf{1}_{\{\forall t \in (0,h-1/k]: B(t) \in D)\}} \big] \bigg)$$

I'm including context, but mainly my questions is about this swap. I'm having trouble justifying how the inequality arises. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of real numbers, remember that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = \inf_{n_0} \{ \sup_{n \ge n_0} x_n \} \tag 1 $$

and

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sup_{n_0} \{ \inf_{n \ge n_0} x_n \} \tag 2$$

*Claim: Let $(x_{m,n})_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double sequence of real numbers, then*

$$\inf_n \big ( \limsup_{m \to \infty} x_{m,n} \big) \ge\limsup_{m \to \infty} \big ( \inf_n x_{m,n} \big) $$

*Proof:*

For all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has

$$x_{m,n} \ge \inf_n \big (x_{m,n}\big)$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}\inf_{m_0} \Big \{ \inf_{n} \big \{ \sup_{m\ge m_0} \big (x_{m,n}\big)  \big \}\Big \} &\ge \inf_{m_0} \Big \{ \sup_{m\ge m_0}\big \{\inf_n \big (x_{m,n}\big)\big \}  \Big \} \\ &\ge \limsup_{m \to \infty} \big ( \inf_n x_{m,n} \big) \end{align}

Where the last inequality follows from (1). But, for any double sequence $(y_{m,n})_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers

$$\inf_m \Big \{ \inf_n y_{m,n} \Big \}=\inf_{m,n} \big (y_{m,n}\big )= \inf_n \Big \{\inf_m y_{m,n} \Big \} $$

Thus, interchanging the infimums, it follows that

$$\inf_{n} \Big \{ \inf_{m_0} \big \{ \sup_{m\ge m_0} \big (x_{m,n}\big)  \big \}\Big \}\ge\limsup_{m \to \infty} \big ( \inf_n x_{m,n} \big)$$

and again by (1) we get

$$\inf_n \big ( \limsup_{m \to \infty} x_{m,n} \big) \ge\limsup_{m \to \infty} \big ( \inf_n x_{m,n} \big) $$

as required.

Comment: Is the inequality $$x_{m,n} \ge \inf_n \big (x_{m,n}\big)$$ actually a whole bunch indexed by $m$?

Comment: Yes, it is the same $m$ on both sides

Comment: Okay so:

$$\inf_{m_0} \Big \{ \inf_{n} \big \{ \sup_{m\ge m_0} \big (x_{m,n}\big)  \big \}\Big \} = \inf_{n} \Big \{ \inf_{m_0} \big \{ \sup_{m\ge m_0} \big (x_{m,n}\big)  \big \}\Big \}$$

follows from:
$$\inf_m \Big \{ \inf_n y_{m,n} \Big \}=\inf_{m,n} \big (y_{m,n}\big )= \inf_n \Big \{\inf_m y_{m,n} \Big \} $$

where

$$y_{m,n} = \sup_{m\ge m_0} \big (x_{m,n}\big)$$

Is that how you swapped infs at the end?

Comment: Actually, you messed up the indexes a little bit. It should be $y_{m,n} = \sup \limits_{s\ge m} \big (x_{s,n}\big)$

Comment: Note that

$$\inf \limits_{n} \ (y_{m,n}) \ge \inf \limits_{m,n} \ (y_{m,n})$$

Therefore, 

$$\inf \limits_{m} \big \{\inf \limits_{n} \ (y_{m,n})\big \} \ge \inf \limits_{m,n} \ (y_{m,n})$$

On the other hand,

$$y_{m,n} \ge \inf \limits_{n} \ (y_{m,n})$$

Which implies 

\begin{align} \inf \limits_{m,n} \ (y_{m,n}) & \ge \inf \limits_{m,n} \big \{\inf \limits_{n} \ (y_{m,n})\big \}\\ & \ge \inf \limits_{m} \big \{\inf \limits_{n} \ (y_{m,n})\big \}\end{align}